# How to always load a parameter (without adding it to every launch file)

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, rosout

[image: Rosanswers logo]

ROS melodic is introducing a new parameter `/rosout_disable_topics_generation`.
It seems this does something I have wanted for long: omitting the (often long) topics list in the rosout messages.

Can I have some sort of global setup so any roscore will set `/rosout_disable_topics_generation` to True?
I want to avoid that every launch file chain must somewhere include a `<param>` tag that sets this parameter.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/301590/how-to-always-load-a-parameter-(without-adding-it-to-every-launch-file)/) by [knxa](https://answers.ros.org/users/29756/knxa/) on ROS Answers with karma: 811 on 2018-08-25

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-08-25**:
I'm confused: are you starting multiple masters?

**Comment by [knxa](https://answers.ros.org/users/29756/knxa/) on 2018-08-25**:
No, but I can see my title wasn't chosen well. Sorry.

I just want this parameter to be set no matter which roslaunch file I run, for any rostest etc., without having to define it multiple places.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-08-26**:
Updated your title. Couldn't really come up with something 'catchy', but this at least covers the question better I believe.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-08-26**:
As to the question I don't believe that is currently supported. Not officialy anyway.

Edit: you might take a look at [wiki/roscore](http://wiki.ros.org/roscore). Editing `roscore.xml` might be a way to get this in there, but that file is managed by your pkg manager by default. I don't ..

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-08-26**:
.. know whether you can provide an override for it. See [ros/ros_comm/tools/roslaunch/resources/roscore.xml](https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/blob/89ca9a7bf288b09d033a1ab6966ef8cfe39e1002/tools/roslaunch/resources/roscore.xml) for the default contents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I don't know of any environment variable (or a similar piece of infrastructure) that you could use for this, but perhaps using the support for loading `roscore.xml` from `/etc/ros` could be used for this.

`roscore` will try to load that file from `/etc/ros` first, and if that fails, default to the file in the `roslaunch` package (which will be in `/opt/ros/$distro/share`). See [ros/ros_comm/tools/roslaunch/src/roslaunch/config.py](https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/blob/89ca9a7bf288b09d033a1ab6966ef8cfe39e1002/tools/roslaunch/src/roslaunch/config.py#L78-L84), lines 78 to 84.

I've not tested this, but you could copy the default file to `/etc/ros` and then add the parameter there.

---

Edit: apparently the value of `ROS_ETC_DIR` on my machine (Xenial, Kinetic) is `/opt/ros/kinetic/etc/ros` instead of `/etc/ros`.

In any case: adding a parameter to `/opt/ros/kinetic/etc/ros/roscore.xml` makes it part of the 'default' set of parameters that get set for every `roscore` launch. Do read the wiki page I linked in my comment for some more information about that file though.

It would have been ideal if `/etc/ros` was also searched, as that would allow per-machine or per-deployment configuration. I seem to remember some discussion a few years ago about exactly this, but can't find it right now.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-08-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [knxa](https://answers.ros.org/users/29756/knxa/) on 2018-08-28**:
I confirm that it works by adding

```
<param name="rosout_disable_topics_generation" value="True" />
```

to

```
/opt/ros/melodic/etc/ros/roscore.xml
```

I agree that it would be nice if I could add this to a non-package controlled file.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-08-28**:
Well, as I wrote, I remember there being quite a bit of discussion about this, and remember Clearpath being involved in it. Seeing as they have quite a few deployment scenarios where this would come in handy, I can imagine it's actually possible. I just can't remember.

**Comment by [knxa](https://answers.ros.org/users/29756/knxa/) on 2019-03-05**:
Just found that the environment var [ROS_ETC_DIR](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0123.html) controls where roscore will look for the roscore.xml file. So with this I can have my own version of roscore.xml and just point to that location.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-03-05**:
I'd actually considered that when posting my answer, see the last `Edit`.

**Comment by [knxa](https://answers.ros.org/users/29756/knxa/) on 2019-03-05**:
Hmmm you're right, sorry I overlooked that.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-03-05**:
No problem.

`ROS_ETC_DIR` can definitely be part of a solution.

Might pay to take a look at a (recent) Clearpath system (Husky, Heron). They tend to use this sort of setup often.